# Developed Module

Tags: module, magento2.2.2

I have 2 instance of magento store in your local system.instance Fresh Magento installation with sample date of Medium Profile and another with blank data.
I want Sync all customer and customer address from Magento Instance 1​ to Magento Instance 2​ (Except password).

● Syncing customer should be achieved by Standard Magento Rest API.

● Developed module should handle case for create and update customer.

● Create and update customer should be on the basis of customer email.

● Create and update customer address should be on the basis of country and zip code.

Comment: This documentation from Magento 2 can help you: https://devdocs.magento.com/guides/v2.0/howdoi/migrate/migrate.html . Even though your approach is different from what standard tool Magento is providing for data migration, you can still try that tool.